# Robotium test framework error

Tags: android, junit, robotium

I am new to `Robotium test framework.`
I have created one sample project in which I am just moving one activity to other on click of a button.

My test case works fine but it gets crash when it comes to second activity..

My testcase code

```
public void testDisplayBlackBox() {
    solo.clickOnButton("Button");
    solo.assertCurrentActivity("Expected MainActivity activity", "SecondActvity");
    }
```

I am getting following error

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: Expected MainActivity activity expected:<SecondAct[]vity> but was:<SecondAct[i]vity>
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Asserter.assertCurrentActivity(Asserter.java:41)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.assertCurrentActivity(Solo.java:588)
at com.example.ddd.MainActivityTest.testDisplayBlackBox(MainActivityTest.java:28)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)
```

Comment: could you please add your MainActivityTest code? Mention which is the line at MainActivityTest.java:28?

Comment: please post the code from where your extending activityInstrumentationTest class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its is not crashing after going to second `activity` it suddenly closes the `activity2` which is a normal behavior  if you want to see previous action use solo.`goBack()`

Answer (score 1):

seems that your string in assertCurrentActivity function has a typo.

```
activity expected:<SecondAct[]vity> but was:<SecondAct[i]vity>
```

check this function. if it still happens provide us some code
EDIT:

TRY: solo.assertCurrentActivity("WHATEVER YOU WANT",SecondActivity.class);

Comment: Thank you for responding...With the above code i am able to move to second activity..i have posted my code above

Comment: I would also suggest you to start with their youtube beginners tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_8euppCz3k